# make: g++: Command not found

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, g++, cygwin

I've checked similar posts and anyone solve my problem. I's very simple but I'm new with eclipse. I'm trying to make a simple example and I'm having this problem.

the make file is just this

```
all: hello.exe

clean:
    rm Hello.o Hello.exe

hello.exe: hello.o
    g++ -g -o hello.exe hello.o

hello.o:
    g++ -c -g main.cpp
```

And I get this error  "make: g++: Command not found"

Thanks for helping.

Comment: First guess: You don't have g++ installed.  :P

Comment: Does `g++` (the GNU C++ compiler) work on the command line?  If not, install it (if you're on Debian/Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install g++`).

Comment: @therefromhere he's building `hello.exe` which indicates he's not on Linux or Unix.

Comment: effectively, I'm in windows. I have cygwin installed and I don't know why I'm having this error

Comment: So, If cygwin includes g++ out of the box why am I having this error?

Comment: @hd1 good point, I missed that.

Comment: No cygwin doesn't include g++ in its default install. It's available by default: you can select it in the wizard. Run the installer again to update your cygwin installation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install the development tools from GNU. I assume you're on windows, in which case you have two options: [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and [mingw](http://www.mingw.org). The former [includes g++](http://horstmann.com/bigcpp/help/gnuwindows/index.html) out of the box. I'm less familiar with mingw, but the [C++ Standard library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/gcc-4.7.2-1/) appears to, also, be available.

See [these installation instructions](http://cs.calvin.edu/curriculum/cs/112/resources/installingEclipse/cygwin/), I'd recommend starting from step 1, if at all possible.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I will add that in addition to the installation instructions given, I had to add C:\cygwin64\bin to the PATH before I could use g++ commands.

Answer (score 10):

`sudo apt install g++` did the trick for on on Ubuntu 20 LTS.

Comment: This worked for me, using WSL2 Ubuntu 20 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Adding for RHEL users, installing development tools resolved the issue on rhel.

Command:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```